# Why is GPS Status eating a third of my battery power?

Tags: battery-life, gps

I'm trying to have as little as possible running when I'm not using my phone.
In the system settings under battery you can see what has been using the most power.
I've been able to disable or uninstall most of those I don't use or need.

Why is [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) listed there for about 33%? I usually don't have GPS enabled.

Should I uninstall it? I got it after [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) told me I should install it.

Comment: If you don't wanna install, just force stop it in setting -> app. If that is draining your battery without using it, you should report to developer. Actually, this really is a great app for my daily use :)

Comment: Ah, look what I found here: http://mobiwia.com/gpsstatus/faq#battery